# Contaminated land data for Scotland?

Tags: environment, land

I'm looking for contaminated land data for Scotland. I know this is managed by [SEPA](http://www.sepa.org.uk/regulations/land/contaminated-land/#four), but I can't find any links to download this data.

Comment: SEPA only has responsibility for contaminated sites where they've been designated as 'special' otherwise the responsibility lies with the local councils.

Comment: @chrisis thanks for clearing that up. After a bit more digging around I've realised that the councils look after the data - but after checking a few council websites, doesn't appear to easily accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but may be of help to those who come after. 
Contaminated land data is collated by the improvement service on their 'spatial hub'. It is not open data, but it can be previewed, by clicking on 'preview' [here](https://www.spatialhub.scot/get-data/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - good to know for future reference. Although when I looked at the contaminated land layer I couldn't see any polygons (on the preview map).

Comment: They are there, but there are a couple of gotchas, first you need to mouse over the layers button and toggle contaminated land on. Second they're really small, so you need to zoom in to your aoi, but they vanish if you zoom in too close! As an example there's one on western boundary of Lanark.

Comment: Ah yeah I see it now thanks - they are just quite thinly spread which I suppose is a good thing! Cheers